# SELECT COUNT Index

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I am a novice with MySQL database optimization.

I have a slow query with the following:

```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total 
     FROM shs_product p 
LEFT JOIN shs_product_description pd 
       ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN shs_product_to_store p2s 
       ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN shs_product_to_category p2c 
       ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id) 
    WHERE pd.language_id = '1' 
      AND p.status = '1' 
      AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
      AND p2s.store_id = '$
```

Can anyone advise on action on index creation to speed up this query?
Which table and which column would you recommend?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Just to add: this and other queries are causing HIGH CPU usage / load. I am also working diligently on my.cnf file, but I am failing. If anyone could make suggestions I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your query is not doing what you think it is doing. Your left joins are actually INNER joins. Move the conditions on table joins to the ON clause of said JOINs.

Comment: Not sure if this will improve speed..but you are reducing your left joins to inner joins with the way you have this query worded...left joins produce nulls when a record is not found (inner join filters them out).  where p2s.store_ID = '$ means any records that have nulls (the records included because you are left joining) are ultimately filtered out on this where clause (IE, this query might as well be all inner joins).  Not really a speed help, but just want to make sure you are aware of that.  The left join to p2c seems extraneous.

Comment: Thank you, Sebas; how do I move the conditions on the table joins to the ON clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three observations:

1. The `where` clause is undoing the outer join to `p2s` and to `pd`.  So you might as well call these inner joins.
2. The `p2c` table is not being used.  Because you are doing a `count(distinct)` you can remove it.
3. Presumably, the ids are integers so you don't need quotes

So, the query is equivalently

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total 
FROM shs_product p JOIN
     shs_product_description pd 
     ON p.product_id = pd.product_id JOIN
     shs_product_to_store p2s 
     ON p.product_id = p2s.product_id 
 WHERE pd.language_id = 1 AND p.status = 1 AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND
       p2s.store_id = '$'
```

For this query, you want an index on `shs_product(status, date_available)`.  You also want indexes on the columns used for joining and in the `where` clauses.  I would suggest:  `shs_product_description(product_id, language_id)` and `shs_product_to_store(product_id, store_id)`.

Finally, assuming that `product_id` is a unique index in `product`, you can phrase this query using `exists` and `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(*)
from shs_product p
where p.status = 1 AND p.date_available <= NOW() and
      exists (select 1
              from shs_product_description pd
              where p.product_id = pd.product_id and pd.language_id = 1
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from shs_product_to_store p2s 
              where p.product_id = p2s.product_id and p2s.store_id = '$'
             );
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Yes, I have those indexes all already. I just need to change the query. Great advice. Thank you...